# using data-toggle on a link for collapsed nav bar

Tags: angularjs

i am using angularjs and bootstrap3.
i have the nav bar and when in the collapse mode and the mobile menu is expanded, if i click on  the link "Restricted" , the var collapse is toggled and the menu goes away(which is what i want).

If i click on the menu and it is expanded and i click on the home icon it toggles collapse as expected. the problem is, if the home is clicked again, the menu shows itself (as expected because we are toggling collapse). My question is how do i set collapse to true when the home button is set?

Thanks for any help

```
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" id="navbar-logo" class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <span title="back to home page" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
           <!-- <img title="UAB Hospital Formulary" src="images/logo.png"> -->
    </a>
```

part of the nav bar:

```
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a data-toggle="collapse=true" data-target=".navbar-collapse" id="navbar-logo" class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <span title="back to home page" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
           <!-- <img title="UAB Hospital Formulary" src="images/logo.png"> -->
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        some stuff
    </div>
```

in the collapsed version of the navbar i have

```
 <div class="visible-xs">
            <ul class="nav collapsed-links" >
                <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" 
                       ng-href="#/list/restricted">Restricted</a></li>
            </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

someone on google groups helped me out on this one.
Here is the link to the http://plnkr.co/edit/m1mIxoGMeLlGkaiyFtSN?p=preview

this piece of code was added in the folder select function

```
 if ( node.expanded ){
    //append
 } else {
    angular.element($event.target).parent().find('treechild').css({display: 'none'})
 }
```